# my JSON url not validating

Tags: php, json

We generate json data using php and my sql and display json data

I feel json data is proper and well formatted, when i display result using php file in proper json format then json validator show error but when i save json data in json file then no error

Please check following url, i use stack.hu to test my json url and i need this json url to fetch data from android code

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.yuvajobs.com/mobileapp/test_json.php

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.yuvajobs.com/mobileapp/test1.json

Both have exactly same data but .php one show error but .json one working

As i need to make an api where if user search anything then we pass that word in db and fetch result, if we make sperate json for each word then its hell for us

**What we are want**

We are a job portal, we are making android app, we use json to fetch data , we have different job category , when anyone click on any job category then it will send request to my php and my php will search data in db according to category and will store all result in array and we encode the array data as json and will display

Comment: There is a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in the reply header of your php. Set headers via PHP or .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending JSON, you should also declare so in your `Content-Type` header. Currently you are using the default Content-Type of `text/html`, which is not appropriate for this case. Instead you should set it to `application/json`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: we have already tried this and still, error, i feel its showing error if its php file, can u test my php url with any json url tester?

Comment: Have you verified the usage of `header()` works, so it apeears in the request?

Comment: how i can verify

Comment: we use error display function and show no error. if header have any error then it will display warning and errors. but none

Comment: This is not about displaying errors or not, this is about the actual headers which are sent. If you open the dev-Tools in your browser and take a look at the networking-tab, you can click on the request an take a look at the headers. There should be one that's called `Content-Type`. This has to be not `text/html`, but instead `application/json'

Comment: can u please check http://www.yuvajobs.com/mobileapp/test2.php this file have header now. can u test if header working fine

Comment: i have checked and it show Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have fixed the content type, http://jsonviewer.stack.hu still returns an error.  It complains that it cannot read the JSON because of some 'Incomplete Chunked Encoding' error, but this is when it sends your URL to its server, to request your JSON server-side.

There are some differences between the responses of those two URLs, the `.json` response contains extra headers (`Accept-ranges` and `Last Modified`).  The JSON Viewer you're using forwards these headers on to its server, so that might be the problem.

Your API works when testing with https://client.restlet.com/ though.

Standalone clients may be easier to use for testing your Android api.  Such as [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).  There are also browser extensions similar to these.